# What are fundamental differences between single dispatch and multiple dispatch?

Tags: programming-languages, programming-paradigms

How do single and multiple dispatch differ?

In particular, I am wondering why some programming languages, both interpreted and compiled (such as Python and Java), natively support single dispatch but not multiple dispatch. Possibly a bit naive to think so, but isn't multiple dispatch a straight-forward generalization of single dispatch? If a programming language implements single dispatch, why would it not implement multiple dispatch? Are the two dispatch methods not philosophically aligned?

Please let me know whether my question is ambiguous and needs clarification.